# iOS 7 - Play sound at specific time when iPhone is locked

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, alarm, screen-lock

I am working on an app with alarm clock functionality, where I currently have an interface to set the alarm time and the timer can be started - this works flawlessly.

What I want to do - I know other apps do this (e.g. Alarm Clock HD) - is to let the user lock the screen and still have the app start playing the alarm sound 8.00 am in the morning.

The point of doing this that I need the time when the user went to sleep and later was woken up by the alarm sound.

How would I go about doing this?

Notice: I wish not to use nslocalnotifications or just prevent the phone from going to sleep.

Comment: Why not local notifications?

Comment: I don't want to be limited to only 30 seconds of audio as this should function as an alarm clock.

And I've seen apps like "Alarm Clock HD" that works like I described above.

Comment: Hi @JakobHalskov, have you found an answer to this ?? I'm looking for something similar, it would be a great help if you can post and answer :)

Comment: I haven't found a solution Apple will approve yet - sorry :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do Clock ringing with app in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995908/how-to-do-clock-ringing-with-app-in-background)